# Problems with load balancing and nginx gcp

Tags: google-app-engine, nginx, google-compute-engine, load-balancing

I am trying to use gcp to host my back end rest api. I have created successfully a vm instsnce ubuntu debian 9 , configured the firewall rules vpc network and now I have to to "make" it listen to some ports, in order the vm instance to accept requests from adresses. I followed the tutorials here: https://geekflare.com/gcp-load-balancer/ and https://www.scaleway.com/en/docs/how-to-configure-nginx-reverse-proxy/ , but neither of them works for me. Using load balancing and running the netstat -l in shh terimal , I get this :

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:bootpc          0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 instance-group-2-ff:ntp 0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 localhost:ntp           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ntp             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 fe80::4001:aff:fea6:ntp [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 localhost:ntp           [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 [::]:ntp                [::]:*
```

and

from nginx :

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:http            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:bootpc          0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 instance-group-for-:ntp 0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 localhost:ntp           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ntp             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 fe80::4001:aff:fea6:ntp [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 localhost:ntp           [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 [::]:ntp                [::]:*
```

and when writing the external ip on web browser : 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.10.3
The reverse-proxy.conf is :

```
 server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

        location / {
                    proxy_pass http://external:80;
  }
}
```

I also tested nginx and everything is ok.
Do you know maybe what is wrong? Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Is there a reason that you are creating your own load balancer instead of using App Engine which handles that automatically for you?

Comment: @gaefan Because I am having problems with the connection, I read a lot that other people that had the same problem with me solved it with load balancing. I now erased because it was not a solution for me!

Comment: @gaefan I created the firewall rules but I am still getting 500. Is there any other configuration that I need to do ?

Comment: Google App Engine (GAE) is a different product from what you are currently using.  I'm suggesting you stop creating your own GCE instances and try GAE instead.  GAE takes care of load balancing for you.